# Error when install Wordpress with mariadb "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Tags: centos5, wordpress, php5, mariadb

```
rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs 
yum install MariaDB-server
```

The above command helped me to install mariadb, also installed Wordpress.  This was a great help. My problem now is when I reboot the server or restart apache here is the error:

```
"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php-mysql so that PHP could connect to a MySQL/MariaDB instance. Do this by

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Comment: I install mariadb without erasing php_mysql and mysql libs. actually I already installed wordpress and create a site but when I restart the httpd the  error occurs

Comment: is this a bug for combining php, mariadb, apache and wordpress. here is my situation: I have a server running with php and mysql, for me to install the mariadb you need to remove mysql-server.

yum remove mysql-server

after removing mysql-server I run this 

rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs

To prevent php_mysql and mysql libs from deletion/conflicts during installation of mariadb

after  that I successfully insyall mariadb and able to install wordpress but if I restart the appache the error occured

“Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.”

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to reinstall php and php related packages.

```
yum remove php*
yum install epel-release
```

You must find the packages for your specific php version. In this example it's `PHP 5.6`

```
yum install php56w php56w-common
```

You may want as well to reinstall other packages depending on your requirements; listing a few here:

```
yum install php56w-mysqlnd php56w-pdo php56w-opcache php56w-mbstring php56w-gd php56w-dom php56w-pear php56w-soap
```

For example you can find a list of packages for PHP 5.6 here https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/#sapis
; or list available packages using `yum list available 'php56w-*'`

Restart your server: `systemctl restart httpd.service`